# Java 9 - Cannot be resolved as a module

Tags: java, eclipse, java-9

Very simple use case, I am using [Eclipse Oxygen 4.7.3a](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/#Latest_Release) that includes support from Java 9. I have two projects that are Java 9 projects:

```
- projectOne
| - src
| - module-info.java
  | - com
    | - package1
      | - first
        | Classificator.java

- projectTwo
| - src
| - module-info.java
  | - com
    | - package2
      | - second
        | Classifiable.java
```

I want to use the `Classifiable` class inside the `Classificator`, so I try to import the second module into the first project.

module-info.java Project 1:

```
module projectOne   {
    requires projectTwo;
}
```

module-info.java Project 2:

```
module projectTwo   {

}
```

Eclipse is giving me the error:

> projectTwo cannot be resolved to a module

Do I have to gather all my Java projects under one "main project" in order to let Eclipse know that all those modules are usable inside it? Or have I missed something else?

Comment: What made you want to choose `project-one` and `project-two` as your module names?  I doubt that would even compile due to the `-`.

Comment: Those* are placeholders, to be honest. I'll edit for the `-`.

Comment: No, you don't need them to be in the same directory. Ideally, your `project-one` defines some `uses`, wnich are `implements` by your `project-two` (or vice-versa). Get the runtime implementation of your used interfaces. For this, both jars/classes must be on the module path.

Comment: Would you mind making it an answer ? As the `modulePath` solved the issue, it is a bad habit to post answer in comments. As Java 9 is fairly new, I think some people might have the issue. Pointing them to your answer may help a lot.

Comment: @YassineBadache there you go...

Comment: Just a detail regarding your directory layout: I assume `module-info.java` and `com/` are members of their respective `src/` folder, right? Indentation makes us think otherwise.

Comment: Oh, yeah true! I'm editing right away, thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't need them to be in the same directory. Ideally, your `project-one` module defines some `uses`, which are implements by your `project-two` module (or vice-versa). Get the runtime implementation of your used interfaces. For this, both jars/classes must be on the module path.

For further information on module build, multi module builds,... you can refer to [this link](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/core-java-tutorial/modules/multi-module-mode.html). Even if you do not use gradle, its [tutorial on java 9 module build](https://guides.gradle.org/building-java-9-modules/) is quite interesting and gives some insight.

Answer (score 0):

While wiring as a service is certainly a viable approach (as described in the other answer), let me add that `requires` can be made to work, too, of course.

The thing that was probably missing from the first approach is: Eclipse still needs to know where to look for modules. In real world projects this will typically be mediated by your build tool of choice plus a plug-in like [m2e](https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/) or [buildship](https://github.com/eclipse/buildship/blob/master/README.md).

If no such plug-in is used, a normal project dependency should be added to the Build Path of project `projectOne` in order to make project `projectTwo` visible. Once the project is on the Build Path the module defined by the project can be resolved in references in `module-info.java`.